# Difficulty implementing Spring Retry Logic for publisher

Tags: java, spring, spring-jms, jmstemplate

I have a Spring Boot application that has a JMS Publisher.  The publisher used retry logic that was in the publisher class that worked fine.  But I want to change that to the Spring Retry Template and put it into the connection factory configuration.

I am having trouble figuring out how to call add the RetryTemplate into the Publisher class.

This is the Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableRetry
public class PurchasedTransServicePublisherConfig {

    @Value("${java.naming.factory.initial.publisher}")
    private String context;

    @Value("${java.naming.provider.url.publisher}")
    private String providerURL;

    @Value("${fedex.jms.LDAP.entryName.publisher}")
    private String ldapEntryName;

    private @Value("${jms.username.publisher:#{null}}") String jmsUserName;
    private @Value("${jms.password.publisher:#{null}}") String jmsPassword;

    @Value("${jms.destinationname.publisher}")
    private String destinationName;

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PurchasedTransServicePublisherConfig.class);

    @Autowired(required = false)
    FxgCipherInitializer jmsParams;

    @Bean
    public JmsTemplate publisherJmsTemplate(final ConnectionFactory publisherConnectionFactory) {
        final JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate();
        jmsTemplate.setConnectionFactory(publisherConnectionFactory);
        jmsTemplate.setPubSubDomain(true);
        jmsTemplate.setDefaultDestinationName(destinationName);
        jmsTemplate.setSessionTransacted(true);
        return jmsTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory publisherConnectionFactory(final JndiTemplate publisherJndiTemplate) throws NamingException {
        final ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) publisherJndiTemplate.getContext().lookup(ldapEntryName);
        final UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter ucf = new UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter();
        ucf.setUsername(((null != jmsParams) ? jmsParams.getUsername() : jmsUserName));
        ucf.setPassword((null != jmsParams) ? jmsParams.getPassword() : jmsPassword);
        ucf.setTargetConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        return ucf;
    }

    @Bean
    public RetryTemplate retryTemplate() {
        RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
        FixedBackOffPolicy fixedBackOffPolicy = new FixedBackOffPolicy();
        fixedBackOffPolicy.setBackOffPeriod(2000l);
        retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(fixedBackOffPolicy);
        SimpleRetryPolicy retryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy();
        retryPolicy.setMaxAttempts(2);
        retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);
        return retryTemplate;
    }


    @Bean
    public JndiTemplate publisherJndiTemplate() {
        final JndiTemplate jndiTemplate = new JndiTemplate();
        final Properties jndiProps = new Properties();
        jndiProps.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, context);
        jndiProps.setProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL, providerURL);
        jndiTemplate.setEnvironment(jndiProps);
        return jndiTemplate;
    }  
}
```

The only change between the working configuration and the RetryTemplate configuration is the addition of the annotation `@EnableRetry` and the method `retryTemplate`

The publisher class originally successfully retried the send messsage using this logic:

```
 private void send(final MessageCreator messageCreator) throws JMSException {
        int sendAttempts = 0;

        while (true) {
            try {
                jmsTemplate.send(messageCreator);
                LOGGER.info("Message Successfully Published");
                break;
            }  catch (RuntimeException e) {
                LOGGER.error("Caught Runtime Exception: {}", e.getMessage());
                sendAttempts++;
                handleJmsExceptionRetry(e, sendAttempts);
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried to implement the retry template like this:

```
 private void send(final MessageCreator messageCreator) throws JMSException {
        while (true) {
            try {
                publisherJmsTemplate.send(messageCreator);
                LOGGER.info("Message Successfully Published");
                break;
            }  catch (RuntimeException e) {
                LOGGER.error("Caught Runtime Exception: {}", e.getMessage()); 
                publisherRetryTemplate.execute(arg0 -> {
                    publisherJmsTemplate.send(messageCreator);
                    return null;
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

The test method that I created to unit test this is below:

```
 @Test
    public void testPublishTmsTrip_WhenPublishFailsMultipleTimes() {
        Mockito.doThrow(RuntimeException.class).when(mockJmsTemplate).send(mockMessageCreator);
        boolean testBoolean = tmsTripPublisher.publishTmsTripMessageEvent("TEST message");
        assertFalse(testBoolean);
    }
```

The problem is when it gets to the `publisherRetryTemplate.execute...`, it does not execute the RetryTemplate method.
Any guidance into how to implement this retry logic would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You don't need a try-catch block to retry a call when an exception is thrown. Just use  publisherRetryTemplate.execute(arg0 -> {
                    publisherJmsTemplate.send(messageCreator);
                    return null;
                });

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `@EnableRetry` unless you are using `@Retryable` on a method.

It's not clear why you have `while (true)` there, or why you initially call outside of the retry template's execute method.

Why not just

```java
private void send(final MessageCreator messageCreator) throws JMSException {
    publisherRetryTemplate.execute(arg0 -> {
         publisherJmsTemplate.send(messageCreator);
         return null;
     });
}
```

?

It's not clear what you mean by "it does not execute the RetryTemplate method".

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have a try-catch block to retry the request. Retry template itself retry the request as it configured(2 retries with 2000ms timeout).

Just use

```
private boolean send(final MessageCreator messageCreator) {       
   try {
       publisherRetryTemplate.execute(arg0 -> {
          publisherJmsTemplate.send(messageCreator);
          LOGGER.info("Message Successfully Published");
          return null;
       });
   } catch (Exception e) {
       LOGGER.error("Caught Exception: {}", e);
       // Error handling logic here
       return false;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you mixed declarative approach with the programmatic one.
You don't need the `@EnableRetry` in your configuration class as long as you don't use the methods annotated with the `@Retryable` and `@Recover`.

If you use programmatic retries with the `RetryTemplate` bean, you don't need to call the `RetryTemplate.execute()` method on exceptions in the catch block.
While defining the `RetryTemplate` bean, you just need to specify the exceptions, which occurrence will start new operation specified in the `execute()` callback.

For example, if you want to retry the operation on the RuntimeException, but don't want to do it on some you CustomException, you have to specify it in the policy map:

```
new ExceptionClassifierRetryPolicy().
        setPolicyMap(ImmutableMap.<Class<? extends Throwable>, RetryPolicy> builder()
            .put(CustomException.class, new NeverRetryPolicy())
            .put(RuntimeException.class, new SimpleRetryPolicy(MAX_RETRY_ATTEMPTS))
            .build());
```